# FFmpeg transcoding libx264 set only one P-frame

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, h.264, gop

I transcoding mpeg2 data to h264 via libx264 codec and need to create the following GOP structure:

> I(IDR) P I P

I try to perform it with the following command:

> ffmpeg -i INPUT -vcodec libx264 -g 4 -bf 0 -refs 1 -acodec copy 
>   OUT.mpg

Check results via ffprobe:

> ffprobe -i OUT.mpg -show_entries frame=key_frame,pict_type
>   -select_streams v -of compact=p=0

And received the following output:

> key_frame=1|pict_type=I
>  key_frame=0|pict_type=P
>   key_frame=0|pict_type=P 
>  key_frame=0|pict_type=P

As you can see the GOP structure is:

> I(IDR) P P P

I think -refs 1 key has no effect. 
Please explain how correct transcode it to necessary GOP I(IDR)PIP ?

Comment: You may have to use x264 standalone encoder with qpfile option.

Comment: `-refs 1`  means use (at most) 1 reference frame. P frames can reference P frames, so it will not affect GOP structure. You do set the GOP structure to 4 `-g 4` and get a 4 frame GOP. So I'm not sure if i"m understanding the issue since `-g 2` should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks to All for answers and explanations. But with -g 2. All I-frames will be IDR and we will receive I(IDR) P structure, but necessary structure is I(IDR) P I P. The third I-frame shouldn't be IDR.